# Adding numerical values in a LaTeX tabular column

Tags: tables, calculations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I automatically calculate sums in a LaTeX table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3851/how-can-i-automatically-calculate-sums-in-a-latex-table)

Does anyone know if the is a TeX/LaTeX package which will make an ordinary `tabular` environment work as a simple spreadsheet?  I am using LaTeX to generate invoices. The invoice is a `tabular` environment with one row per item and the item amount in the last column. The item amount is entered as a simple number, then a macro prints it with the `$` sign. I am looking for something that will add up all the numbers in the last column, calculate the total and show it in the last row, last column. Thanks. Buddy.

Comment: Please take a look at the question Hendrik has suggested as the answers there might help you. If they do, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If they don't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Answer (score 3):

I know  [spreadtab](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/spreadtab/)

This is a very fine package and you can make a lot of things with this package. I know the author so if you have a problem, I can help you.

Comment: This looks like a very interesting package!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) to either generate the data or read it in from a CSV spreadsheet file. The package can do calculations on the data from within your document as well.