# Can LaTeX perform calculation like Excel formula table?

Tags: calculations

I wonder if this feature is available in TeX system? For example, given a formula within a table, it can apply the formula and display data after the calculation.

Comment: That depends on the complexity of the formula. Reasonably simple things can be done with [tag:pgfplotstable], but things become quite tedious relatively quickly. Could you provide an example of the kind of things you'd want to do?

Comment: There's the package `spreadtab` which looks quite promising on this respect.

Comment: @Jake: Working on my Physics Lab, my professor asked us to use Excel but I don't have Office on my system for a long time. So I wonder if the TeX system could do something similar to Excel. I don't think I need a really complex formula, maybe a summation of all column would be sufficient.

Comment: There also the package `calc` to do simple arithmetics with lengths and counters.

Comment: Great question, and great answer. Just as an aside, there's OpenOffice which is free and open source :)

Comment: From what I've seen (and used), these kind of things are usually done via some kind of R integration, like Sweave or knit...

Comment: I second @cmhughes' suggestion: It's great that this is possible with TeX, but you should install OpenOffice so you can have a real choice. Just because TeX can do something doesn't mean it's the easiest way to do it. (Also with OpenOffice you can generate a spreadsheet that your prof can read with Excel).

Comment: see also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3851/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is the package [`spreadtab`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab) which provides spreadsheet like features. These examples are taken from the documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{rr|r}}
 22       & 54       & a1+b1 \\
 43       & 65       & a2+b2 \\
 49       & 37       & a3+b3 \\
 \hline
 a1+a2+a3 & b1+b2+b3 & a4+b4
\end{spreadtab}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|r|ccc|}}
 \hline
 @ values of $x$ & -5       &        -1 &        4 \\
 @ $f(x)=2x$     & 2*[0,-1] &  2*[0,-1] & 2*[0,-1] \\
 \hline
\end{spreadtab}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|*{10}{c}|}}
 \hline
 @$\times$        & 1                     & \STcopy{>}{b1+1}  & & & & & & & & \\
 \hline
 1                & \STcopy{>,v}{!a2*b!1} &                   & & & & & & & & \\
 \STcopy{v}{a2+1} &                       &                   & & & & & & & & \\
                  &                       &                   & & & & & & & & \\
                  &                       &                   & & & & & & & & \\
                  &                       &                   & & & & & & & & \\
                  &                       &                   & & & & & & & & \\
                  &                       &                   & & & & & & & & \\
                  &                       &                   & & & & & & & & \\
                  &                       &                   & & & & & & & & \\
                  &                       &                   & & & & & & & & \\
 \hline
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple example of using R, knitr and xtable to produce a LaTeX table.

Assume you have the following document called `test.rnw`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
library(xtable)
sheet <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), y=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
sheet$z <- sheet$x + sheet$y
print(xtable(sheet))
@
\end{document}
```

In short, the code between `<<>>=` and `@` in the `rnw` file is replaced by the latex output generated in a new `tex` file. In particular, `xtable` is a package and function that can convert a data frame into a latex table. It has a large number of options, but in the above example I've relied on the defaults.

To convert the file into latex and then to pdf you could just open the rnw file in the open source R IDE called [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/) and click "Compile PDF". Or you could issue commands like this from the command line.

```
Rscript -e 'library(knitr); knit("test.rnw")'
pdflatex test.tex
```

It would produce output like this:

[image]

To run the above example, you would need to install:

- R: http://www.r-project.org/
- knitr: `install.packages('knitr')` in R
- xtable: `install.packages('xtable')` in R

For more information check out the knitr website: http://yihui.name/knitr/

Answer (score 10):

If you use LuaTeX you can extend TeX with any C math library and
create Lua bindings.

To create the necessary bindings the program
[SWIG](http://swig.org/) can be used. Here is a ConTeXt example
which uses the [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) algebra
system to do the calculations.

**Generate the binding**

file:`pari.i`

```
%module pari
%{
#include "pari.h"
ulong overflow;
%}

%ignore gp_variable(char *s);
%ignore setseriesprecision(long n);
%ignore killfile(pariFILE *f);
%ignore pari_vfprintf(FILE *file, const char *fmt, va_list ap);
%ignore pari_vprintf(const char *fmt, va_list ap);
%ignore pari_vsprintf(const char *fmt, va_list ap);
%ignore out_vprintf(PariOUT *out, const char *fmt, va_list ap);

%include "pari/parisys.h";
%include "pari/paristio.h";
%include "pari/paricom.h";
%include "pari/parigen.h";
%include "pari/paridecl.h";
%include "pari/parierr.h";
%include "pari/paricast.h";
%include "pari/paritune.h";
%include "pari/pariinl.h";

%inline %{
GEN uti_mael2(GEN m,long x1,long x2)
{return mael2(m,x1,x2);}
%}
```

Generate the binding with

```
swig -lua -I/usr/include pari.i
```

then compile the module

```
gcc -ansi -I/usr/include/pari -I/usr/include/lua5.1       -fPIC -c pari_wrap.c -o pari_wrap.o
gcc -Wall -ansi -shared -I/usr/include/pari       pari_wrap.o -lpari -lm -o pari.so
```

Now the module is available in LuaTeX with `require("pari")`.

**Using the library**

```
\startluacode
  require("pari")
  pari.pari_init(4000000,500000)
  thirddata = thirddata or {}
  local function sum(X,a,b,expr,start)
    local start = start or '0.'
    local res = pari.gp_read_str(string.format(
      "sum(%s=%s,%s,%s,%s)",X,a,b,expr,start))
    res = pari.GENtoTeXstr(res)
    return res
  end
  thirddata.sum = sum
\stopluacode

\starttext

\startformula
  \sum_{k=0}^{30}\frac{4(-1)^k}{2k+1}=
    \luacode{context(thirddata.sum(
       "k",0,30,"4*(-1)^k/(2*k+1)","0"))}
\stopformula

\startformula
  \sum_{k=0}^{3}\frac{1}{x^2+k}=
    \luacode{context(thirddata.sum(
       "k",0,3,"1/(x^2+k)","0"))}
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

The result of this code:

[image: result]

Since this approach does not make use of any ConTeXt features this code should work in LaTeX as well with only minor modifications. However, it only works with LuaTeX.

This description is based on a
[talk](http://www.gust.org.pl/bachotex/2011-en/presentations/Scarso_2_2011)
by Luigi Scarso at BachoTeX 2011. All credits go to him.

Comment: I do not understand all your explanations. What do I have to do if I want to use PARI/GP in LuaTeX? What should I download? (I use Windows 10.)