# Is it possible to perform arithmetic on the entries in a table?

Tags: tables, arithmetic

I want LaTeX to automatically sum the entries in a certain table column. I know these entries will always be integers, but I can't think of a way to 'grab' their values. My first thought was something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\newcount\markcount
\markcount=0
\newcount\tmpcount
\begin{tabular}{c>{\tmpcount}c<{\advance\markcount by\tmpcount\the\tmpcount}}
a & 1 \\
b & 2 \\
\end{tabular}
\the\markcount
\end{document}
```

My thinking here was that the next number TeX encounters after the first `\tmpcount` in each row is the entry in the appropriate cell. Of course this fails due to things happening in the wrong order. Is it possible to implement something like this? I could do it by putting a command in each cell containing an integer to be summed, but there's no fun in that.

Comment: Posting a question somehow makes it easier to find a duplicate. It's a bit like losing something and buying a replacement; one always finds the original item immediately afterwards. [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70860/2417](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70860/2417)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for the complicated answers like `spreadtab` if all you want to do is summing up all values in a single column. The following does that using the `collcell` package, a `\newcolumntype` and a small auxiliary macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{collcell}

\newcount\markcount
\markcount=0

\newcount\tmpcount
\newcolumntype\summingInt[2]
  {>{\collectcell{\summingIntCell{#1}}}#2<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcommand\summingIntCell[2]
  {%
    \tmpcount=\numexpr#2\relax
    \global\advance#1by\tmpcount
    \the\tmpcount
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c\summingInt\markcount{c}}
a & 1 \\
b & 2 \\
c & 1+2 \\
\end{tabular}
\the\markcount
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did think that spreadtab looked like overkill for my problem!