# Mathematical functions inside LaTeX tables

Tags: tables, automation

I have several tables where I have tables which may look like this:

```
-------------------------------------
| X | Y | X + Y | X - Y | (X + Y)/2 |
-------------------------------------
|   |   |       |       |           |
|   |   |       |       |           |
|   |   |       |       |           |
-------------------------------------
```

I mean X, Y are the data and columns 3, 4, 5 are derived from X and Y.

Typing in contents of column 3, 4, 5 are subject to human error and mistakes (can be embarrassing). I was looking to get an idea as to how you solve this problem in LaTeX tables. Is there a package capable of doing this?

When you copy-paste an Excel table, there is very little scope for such errors. Is something similar possible in LaTeX?

Comment: I suppose you want the calculations to be made automatically while printing the results upon compilation, right?

Comment: I'm sure [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) can also be used for this.

Comment: The following question is only about sums, but maybe it's still it's a duplicate: [How can I automatically calculate sums in a LaTeX table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3851)

Answer (score 16):

One way to do this would be to use `pgfplotstable` as in the example that follows. If you need to do more complex analysis, you can create a csv file that can be editted in excel and imported using `pgfplotstable` or `datatool` package. You will find quite a few examples of it under [`datatool`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datatool) and [`pgfplotstable`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplotstable) tag.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
  \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{
    x,y,
    1,6,
    2,4,
    3,5,
    4,7,
    5,8,
  } \data

  \begin{table}
   \pgfplotstableset{create on use/a/.style={create col/expr={\thisrow{x}+\thisrow{y}}}}
   \pgfplotstableset{create on use/b/.style={create col/expr={\thisrow{x}-\thisrow{y}}}}
   \pgfplotstableset{create on use/c/.style={create col/expr={(\thisrow{x}+\thisrow{y})/2}}}
   \pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={x,y,a,b,c},
     columns/x/.style={column name={$x$}, column type={c}, },
     columns/y/.style={column name={$y$}, column type={c}, },
     columns/a/.style={column name={$x+y$}, column type={c}, },
     columns/b/.style={column name={$x-y$}, column type={c}, },
     columns/c/.style={column name={$(x+y)/2$}, column type={c}, },
   ]{\data}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample table]

The following example adds some more eye-candy and illustrates how to import data from a file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}  % Typeset table and manipulate column entries
\usepackage{booktabs}       % Nicer horizontal rules for tables
%\usepackage{array}         % To align column entries by decimal separator

\usepackage{filecontents}   % To illustrate importing data from external file
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv} % Sample contents of data.csv file
    x,      y,
    1,      6,
    2,      4,
    3,      5,
    4,      7,
    5,      8,
    4.4,    7,
    512,    81,
\end{filecontents*}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{data.csv}\data

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \pgfplotstableset{create on use/a/.style={create col/expr={ \thisrow{x}+\thisrow{y}}}}
    \pgfplotstableset{create on use/b/.style={create col/expr={ \thisrow{x}-\thisrow{y}}}}
    \pgfplotstableset{create on use/c/.style={create col/expr={(\thisrow{x}+\thisrow{y})/2}}}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset%
    [columns={x,y,a,b,c},
        every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
        every nth row={5}{before row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        columns/x/.style={column name={$x$}, dec sep align},
        columns/y/.style={column name={$y$}, dec sep align},
        columns/a/.style={column name={$x+y$}, dec sep align},
        columns/b/.style={column name={$x-y$}, dec sep align},
        columns/c/.style={column name={$\frac{x+y}{2}$}, dec sep align},
    ]{\data}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: another sample table]

Comment: It would be nice if you could change the alignment in the last column. I am sure `siunitx` or `dcolumn` could help here but if it can be done with `pgfplotstabble` (only) then that'd be nicer.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen this can be done by adding `dec sep align` to corresponding `column` `style`. I have added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 13):

An example using the [`spreadtab`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{*{5}{>{$}r<{$}}}}
\toprule
@x & @y & @x+y & @x-y & @\dfrac{x+y}{2}\\
\midrule
1 & 2 & \STcopy{>1,v4}{!a2+b2} & \STcopy{>1,v4}{!a2-b2} & \STcopy{>1,v4}{!(a2+b2)/2} \\
3 & 2 & & &  \\
-3 & -6 & & &   \\
9 & -2 & & &  \\
10 & 5 & & &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very nice, but would look even nicer if the headers for the last three columns were more centered over the column contents.

Answer (score 7):

This can also be accomplished using [the `collcell`  package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) which allows one to intercept each of the data elements from `tabular`/`array` for further processing.

[image]

### Notes:

- I used `array` below as the material was all math. This could just as easily have been `tabular`.
- I have used `newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) as I prefer that syntax versus the `\newif` syntax. But if you don't want to include an additional package it should be pretty straightforward to adapt this to use `\newif` or [some other conditional methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577).
- [The `pgf` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package was used for math processing but any method of computing the values you need would work.  Note that `pgf` uses degrees for the trignometric functions by default. Apply the `rad()` function if that is not desired: `sin(rad(<value>))`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}% for toggles
\usepackage{collcell} 
\usepackage{xifthen} 
\usepackage{pgf}% for math

\newcommand{\ColumnXData}{}
\newcommand{\ColumnYData}{}
\newcommand*{\ComputeColumnA}[1]{}%

\newtoggle{DoneWithHeader}
\togglefalse{DoneWithHeader}
\newcommand{\DoneWithHeader}{\global\toggletrue{DoneWithHeader}}

% Automatically reset this toggle at the end of the array
\let\OldEndArray\endarray
\def\endArray{\global\togglefalse{DoneWithHeader}\OldEndArray}

% Define the operations for the various columns.

\newcommand*{\FormatNumber}[2][]{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=5,#1]{#2}}
\newcommand*{\ComputeColumnU}{%
    \pgfmathparse{\ColumnXData + \ColumnYData}%
    \FormatNumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}%
\newcommand*{\ComputeColumnV}{
    \pgfmathparse{(\ColumnXData)^2 + 3*(\ColumnYData)}%
    \FormatNumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}%
\newcommand*{\ComputeColumnW}{%
    \pgfmathparse{sin(\ColumnXData + \ColumnYData)}%
    \FormatNumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}%

\newcounter{ColumnCount}
\newcommand*{\SetColumnData}[1]{%
    \iftoggle{DoneWithHeader}{%
        \stepcounter{ColumnCount}
        % This could clearly be made more efficient but is easier to read this way
        \ifthenelse{\arabic{ColumnCount}=1}{\xdef\ColumnXData{#1}#1}{}
        \ifthenelse{\arabic{ColumnCount}=2}{\xdef\ColumnYData{#1}#1}{}
        \ifthenelse{\arabic{ColumnCount}=3}{\ComputeColumnU}{}
        \ifthenelse{\arabic{ColumnCount}=4}{\ComputeColumnV}{}
        \ifthenelse{\arabic{ColumnCount}=5}{\ComputeColumnW\setcounter{ColumnCount}{0}}{}
        % Note that in the above we wsed the fact that column `W` is last  
        % to reset the column counter so that for the next row we know 
        % which are the data columns.  If this won't always be the case
        % you could manually \setcounter{ColumnCount}{0} at the end of each row.
    }{%
        #1%
    }%
}%
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\SetColumnData}{c}<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\SetColumnData}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\SetColumnData}{r}<{\endcollectcell}}


\begin{document}
$
\begin{array}{C C C C L}
 x & y & x + y & x^2+3y & \sin (x+y) \DoneWithHeader \\ 
 10 & 20 & & & \\
 20 & 40 & & & \\
\end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, I like the way you used `collcell` in combination with a “toggle”. But why do you use `\ComputeColumn?{#1}`? The `\Compute*` macros don't have an argument and in those columns `#1` are empty anyway. In fact, you can remove `{#1}` entirely from those columns. For efficiency and clarity I'd use `\ifcase`: `\ifcase\value{ColumnCount}\xdef\ColumnXData{#1}#1\or\xdef\ColumnYData{#1}#1\or\ComputeColumnU\or\ComputeColumnV\or\ComputeColumnW\setcounter{ColumnCount}{-1}\fi\stepcounter{ColumnCount}`

Comment: Thanks. Have updated solution to eliminate the unused #1.