# Create a table with calculations of binomial and poisson distribution

Tags: tables, calculations

Well, I was looking for some tables on the internet about the binomial and poisson distribution (not the cumulative ones) in LaTeX format. But I've only found the [code of the cumulative distributions](http://www.york.ac.uk/depts/maths/tables/sources.htm), which I don't want. Then I looked around for other formats (not LaTeX), but the only I've found are large tables (3–4 pages).

So I'm thinking if it's possible to make LaTeX do the calculations and then give me the table, based on a few variables.
Is this possible?

The final idea is to get [this](http://cl.ly/1a2O2H1L191v/Binomial_y_Poisson.pdf), which is the *horrible* table the teacher gave us.

**EDIT:** 
Here is my original idea (the only way I know to do it):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=2mm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \c in {2,...,7}{
        \def\n{0.6*\c}
        \draw (-1,-\n^2/2 -\n/2) node {$\c$};
        \draw (-1.5,-\n^2/2 -\n/2 + 0.3) -- (22,-\n^2/2 -\n/2 + 0.3);
        \foreach \k in {0,...,\c}{
        \draw (0, -\n^2/2 -\n/2 -0.6*\k) node {$\k$};
        \foreach \p/\h in {0.01/1,0.05/2,0.1/3,0.15/4,0.2/5,0.25/6,0.3/7,0.3333333333/8,0.35/9,0.4/10,0.45/11,0.49/12,0.5/13}{
        \draw (1.6*\h, -\n^2/2 -\n/2 -0.6*\k) node {\pgfmathparse{\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^(\k)*(1-\p)^(\n-\k)}\pgfmathresult};
        }
        }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It needs some tweaking, but this is the original idea. The problem is that I can't make `\c` go to 10, I get an *Arithmetic Overflow* (which I don't know what is it), and, of course, this is not a real table.

**EDIT2:** Here it is my second edition. Now with some minor problems, but almost solved by @Qrrbrbirlbel. There are still some minor problems which I have ignored, because it's not necessary to me, but may be future people will ask about it:

- First, it doesn't work well if you try to write `\myHeadList{0.1,0.5,0.10,...,0.30}` with `...`, the PGF has some problems here (with non integers numbers). This is partially solved in Qrrbrbirlbel's answer.
- Second, to alternate color in rows, we can use `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` in the preamble and `\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}` inside the document. But with `booktabs` this doesn't work quite well.

Comment: This is essentially a simple numerical computation, so LuaTeX is ideally suited for it. See [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX#Loops_without_worrying_about_expansion) for an example of a much simpler calculation (the lualatex solution will be similar). On a different note, why do you consider the table given by your teacher to be _horrible_. To me, it looks like a very well typeset table.

Comment: I've never used nothing different than LaTeX, so I hope there are other options, but I will look for ConTeXt. About the document, well, is horrible because this is the document he gave us, this .pdf. And I prefer a clean table, with no noise and black points around the document.

Comment: The same solution is possible in LuaLaTeX as well. The important thing is to use LuaTeX to do the calculations rather than doing them in TeX. You can also consider using your favorite programming language to do the calculation and generate the relevant LaTeX code.

Comment: I don't have a favorite programming language since I don't know how to program. I know LaTeX, and Mathematica understands english (online version), so there is no programming in my life.

Comment: With the `pgf` math library this should be doable, but you should compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. And where you want the calculations show the formula you want applied. Or, see for example a similar question: [Mathematical functions inside LaTeX tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76505/mathematical-functions-inside-latex-tables/).

Comment: There is no *problem* at all, I can't include a MWE because I don't have. I know how to write the entire table manually, but I'm looking for an automated method. Similar to `\foreach` but for making tables. As I see in your link may be `pgfplotstable` or `spreadtabs` could achieve my objetive. The only MWE I can think about is the table I want to make.

Comment: This sort of problem is made for the [sagetex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/) package. See page 9 and 10 of example.pdf for a similar (but simpler) problem.

Comment: @Manuel: Create a few rows of the table, and for the column where the values are computed show the equation that is used to compute that column. That would be a MWE, then we just need to complete that entry to solve your problem, not try to set up the table, or try to determine the formula you want to compute that column with.

Comment: I added my idea.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following code shows a solution without the use of external applications.

## Binomial distribution

I now have included PGF's own `fpu` library. *Hopefully its setup is correct.*
Even `n > 8` will compile now (before: `! Dimension too large.`, this was due to the calculation of the binomial coefficient.)

#### Packages used:

- [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for changing the paper layout,
- [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for nice layout of tables (`\top`-, `\mid`- and `\toprule`)
- [`pgf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for the calculations,

  - `fpu` library,
  - `pgf/number format`,
- [`pgffor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgffor) for the `\foreach` loops, and
- [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) for the simple composing of the table contents.
- *[`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\binom` and `\frac` should be used instead of `\choose` and `\over`!*

#### How to use.

There exists one user macro: `\binomTable[<zero>]{<start n>}{<end n>}`.

The optional `<zero>` argument decides whether zero cells (`0.0000`) should be typeset at all (`0`: `0.0000` is typeset, everything else: `0.0000` is not typeset).
[This is hard-coded, any change to the `/pgf/number format/precision` key will have to be shadowed there manually.]

The second and third argument define the start and the end *n*, respectively.

#### Binomial coefficient

For the bionomial coefficient I used the following formula with `i = \j`
[image]

#### [`pgfplotstable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable)?

Yes, please.
<sub>I don't know how to use `pgfplotstable`.</sub>

### Code

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgf,pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=4}

%%% Defining basic stuff
\def\myHeadList{0.01, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30, 1/3, 0.35, 0.40, 0.45, 0.49, 0.50}
%\def\startN{9}
%\def\endN{10}

\newif\ifsomanyzeroesshouldbeprinted
\newcommand*{\binomTable}[3][0]{% #1  = 0 => results in the form 0.0000 are typeset
                                % #1 != 0 => results in the form 0.0000 are omitted
                                % #2 = startN
                                % #3 = endN
    \edef\startN{#2}%
    \edef\endN{#3}%
    \expandafter\ifnum#1=0\relax%
        \somanyzeroesshouldbeprintedtrue%
    \else%
        \somanyzeroesshouldbeprintedfalse%
    \fi%
    %
    %%% Building head of table
    \def\myHead{ $n$ & $k$ & $n\choose k$}%
    \foreach \p in \myHeadList {%
        \xappto\myHead{& {$\p$}}%
    }%
    \appto\myHead{\\}%
    %
    %%% Bulding body of table
    \def\myTable{}%
    \def\myN{\startN,...,\endN}%
    \foreach \n in \myN {%
        \foreach \k in {0,...,\n}{%
            \ifnum\k=0\relax%
                \xappto\myTable{\noexpand\midrule\n}%
            \fi%
            \xappto\myTable{& \k}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\binomProduct}{1}%
            \xdef\myTempValue{\binomProduct}%
            \ifnum\k=0\relax%
                \xdef\oldK{\k}%
            \else%
                    \foreach \j in {1,...,\k}{%
                        \pgfmathsetmacro{\binomProduct}{\myTempValue*(\n+1-\j)/\j}%
                        \xdef\myTempValue{\binomProduct}%
                    }%
            \fi%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myTempValue}{round(\myTempValue)}%
            \xappto\myTable{& \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,set thousands separator={\,},min exponent for 1000 sep=4]{\myTempValue}}%
            \foreach \p in \myHeadList {%
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{\myTempValue*\p^(\k)*(1-\p)^(\n-\k)}%
                \ifsomanyzeroesshouldbeprinted%
                    \xappto\myTable{& \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber{\result}}%
                \else%
                \ifdim\result pt<0.00005pt\relax%
                        \gappto\myTable{&}%
                    \else%
                        \xappto\myTable{& \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber{\result}}%
                    \fi%
                \fi%
            }%
            \gappto\myTable{\\}%
        }%
    }%
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\formulae{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        $\displaystyle p(\xi=k)={{n}\choose{k}} p^k q^{n-k}$ \\
        $\displaystyle  {n\choose k}=\prod_{j=1}^k {n+1-j \over j}$
    \end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}

\binomTable[1]{2}{8}
\begin{tabular}{rrr*{13}{r}}
    \toprule\myHead\myTable\midrule\myHead\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill\formulae

\binomTable[1]{9}{11}
\begin{tabular}{rrr*{13}{r}}
    \toprule\myHead\myTable\midrule\myHead\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill\formulae

\binomTable[1]{12}{14}
\begin{tabular}{rrr*{13}{r}}
    \toprule\myHead\myTable\midrule\myHead\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill\formulae

\binomTable[1]{15}{16}
\begin{tabular}{rrr*{13}{r}}
    \toprule\myHead\myTable\midrule\myHead\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill\formulae
\end{document}
```

### Output

These are old images, the current code adds another column where `n \choose k` is given.

[image]
[image]
[image]

## Poisson distribution

Your code looks fine in my eyes.

PGF’s `\foreach` is known to have precision problems with `...` and non-integer values.
My work-around: Use

```
\foreach \ll in \myLList {%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{.1*\ll}
```

and then you can create your tables with

```
\poissonTable[1]{1,...,40}{12}
```

Interestingly `\pgfmathsetmacor{\l}{\ll/10}` won’t work.

In my given example below I used `{.1*1,.1*...,.1*40}` and parsing that to `\l`. The macro `\poissonTable` takes `1`, `.1*` and `40` as separated parameters whereas the macro `\poissonTableL` expects the list itself.

I added an option to space every _5_th row by testing whether `\l` is divisible by `.5`. We could just use a row-counter we can check for divisibility, but that would give us an separate last row in the second example (which is like your professor's).

Testing for the last row works out of the box with `\poissonTable` but needs a little help for `\poissonTable`.

This solution is very special and probably will need extra care if the rows differ very much from this scheme.

Maybe you want a more explicit sort of giving the rows like in [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83770/16595) where you could say `{.1,.2,.3,.4,[1].5,.6,.7,.8,.9,[1]1,…}` so that rows with `[<x>]` get `<x>ex`-spacing …?

### Code (without output)

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgf,pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=4}

\edef\mysecondtest{false}%
\def\mc#1{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newif\ifsomanyzeroesshouldbeprinted
\newcommand*{\poissonTable}[5][0]{% #1   = 0 => results in the form 0.0000 are typeset
                                  % #1 != 0 => results in the form 0.0000 are omitted
                                  % #2 = startN
                                  % #3 = midN
                                  % #4 = endN
                                  % #5 = endK
    \edef\startN{#2}\edef\midN{#3}\edef\endN{#4}%
    \edef\myLList{\midN\startN,\midN...,\midN\endN}%
    \edef\lastN{\midN\endN}%
    \poissonTableL[#1]{\myLList}{#5}
}
\newcommand*{\poissonTableL}[3][0]{% #1   = 0 => results in the form 0.0000 are typeset
                                   % #1 != 0 => results in the form 0.0000 are omitted
                                   % #2 = Liste
                                   % #3 = endK
    \edef\myLList{#2}
    \edef\endK{#3}%
    \expandafter\ifnum#1=0\relax%
        \somanyzeroesshouldbeprintedtrue%
    \else%
        \somanyzeroesshouldbeprintedfalse%
    \fi%
    %%% Building head of table
    \def\myLHead{\mc{$\lambda$} }%
    \foreach \k in {0,...,\endK} {%
        \ifnum\k=0\relax%
            \xappto\myLHead{& \noexpand\mc{\llap{$k\to{}$}$\k$}}% or \to replaced by =
        \else%
            \xappto\myLHead{& \noexpand\mc{\k}}%
        \fi
        }%
    \appto\myLHead{\\}%
    %%% Bulding body of table
    \def\myLTable{}%
    \foreach \ll in \myLList {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{\ll}%
        \xappto\myLTable{ $\l$}%
        \foreach \k in {0,...,\endK}{%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\Lresult}{e^(-\l)*((\l)^(\k))/((\k)!)}%
            \ifsomanyzeroesshouldbeprinted%
                \xappto\myLTable{& \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber{\Lresult}}%
            \else\ifdim\Lresult pt<0.00005pt\relax%
                     \gappto\myLTable{&}%
                \else%
                     \xappto\myLTable{& \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber{\Lresult}}%
                \fi%
            \fi%
        }%
    \gappto\myLTable{\\}%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastRow}{\ll==\lastN?"0":"1"}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastRow}{\mysecondtest?"0":"\lastRow"}%
    \pgfmathparse{mod(\l,.5)==0?"[\lastRow ex]":""}%
    \xappto\myLTable{\pgfmathresult}%
    }%
    \edef\mysecondtest{false}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\poissonTable[1]{1}{.1*}{40}{12}
\begin{tabular}{rr*{13}{r}}
    \toprule\myLHead\midrule\myLTable\midrule\myLHead\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\edef\lastN{10}%
\def\mysecondtest{mod(\ll,1)==0}%
\poissonTableL[1]{.1*1,.1*...,.1*20,.1*22,.1*24,.1*...,.1*40,5,6,...,10}{12}
\begin{tabular}{rr*{13}{r}}
    \toprule\myLHead\midrule\myLTable\midrule\myLHead\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, looks great. I guess next step is trying `pgfplotstable` :)

Comment: Really nice answer!

Comment: Haha - I feel abashed now. Clearly a perfect answer! Which part of the code produces the \hline between? I woudl be happy if could elaborate the code a little bit. What happens here?

Comment: @percusse Thanks, your comment made me remember [another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82501/16595) where I used a similar approach to compose content that is actually later used inside a `tikzpicture`. I find `pgfplotstable`'s syntax … _very_ different. `;)`

Comment: Bfff... that's amazing. This is what I was looking for. I'm going to play with it a little (trying to make the other table), and I will come back an ask some things (related to row colors, inserting this in a document, etc.). But I really thank you, this is a beautiful answer.

Comment: I think you are being modest. You are way above the requirements to use `pgfplotstable`. Even I can use it :) But I agree the key=value system is quite involved and takes time to digest how things are handled in which order.

Comment: Okey (Remember I don't know anything I'm doing). I've tweaked your code to get my second table (again, I don't know how some of your commands work, but my table is generated). But I have some minor problems which I've added in the question.

Comment: @Manuel See my updated answer on the topic of the `\foreach`-`...` problem. Colors and lines (especially `booktabs`’) are usually considered not to be used together. (→ [Professional-looking tables with alternating row colors?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33758)) You could also consider coloring spans of lines, using extra `\midrule`s or adding vertical space every five or ten rows (as in your professor's table).

Comment: I've already read that, but in this case, I think it's absolutely better to have colors, because the person who is reading only wants to find a number/cell. And the colors may really help. Anyway, I don't know how to add extra space or extra `\midrule` every *n* rows. And could you add my code to your answer so everything is together? Thanks. About the `...`, if there's no solution, I prefer manually than `\ll` or `\l`.

Comment: @Manuel I have given some ideas and a full code in my updated answer.

Comment: If `{.1*1,.1*...,.1*40}` syntax is causing trouble you can switch to `[evaluate=\x as \scaledx using 0.1*\x]` key and give the list as integers again.

Comment: @Manuel I've updates the code of the binomial distribution. The update includes (a) improvement of code (`n \choose k` gets only calculated once), (b) the result of `n \choose k` is rounded to the nearest integer to get more precision (I have the feeling that `fpu` _is not_ set up correct) and (c) typeset in an additional column. I have _not_ updated the images.

Comment: I don't really get your last change, but now it works with PGF's `...`. So now it fits me. Thank you.

Comment: Amazing contribution, wow! May I ask two quick questions: first, how come inserting a bit of horizontal space (e.g.``\hspace{1x}``) inside ``llap`` just before ``$k\to{}$`` in the Poisson table is giving me errors? And how could I remove some zeros inside the ``lambda`` column, to have ``1.0`` below ``0.9`` instead of the ``1.0000000000`` that I'm currently getting? (values from ``0.1`` to ``0.9`` are correctly formatted without unnecessary decimals, but this breaks down from ``1.0`` on below). Thanks!!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel +1 Very nice work! Very complex work, made in LaTeX. I make, for my student, a similar work only for approximation of normal distribution with binomial distribution. But in Excel! A lot more easier than in LaTeX. At this time the word 'LaTex' was for me completely unknown...

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Thanks. Though, 10 years later, I don't think I would do it the same way.

Answer (score 9):

It is quite simple. If you are familiar with **Matlab** or **GNU R**. I prepared a **Matlab** example for the first row. It is only semi-automatic -- you need to modify the result manually. But I guess it takes not more than 2 hours until you are satisfied (depending on your experience of course).

Here's the **Matlab** code:

```
%% Generate first row
% http://f.cl.ly/items/1z2p0g2H410J3K0v1z32/Binomial_y_Poisson.pdf

n = 2;
for k=0:1:2
    i=1;
    for p=[0.01 0.05 0.15 0.20 0.30 1/3 0.35 0.40 0.45 0.50]
        Result(k+1,i) = binopdf(k,n,p)
        i=i+1
    end
end

%% Save to file
% Problem: Still no \\ at the end of each row
try
delete myResult1File
catch
end

dlmwrite('myResult1File.txt',Result,'delimiter','&','newline','pc','precision','%1.4f')

%% Add \\\r\n to each row

myFileIn = fopen('myResult1File.txt');
myFileOut = fopen('myResult2File.txt','w');

while ~feof(myFileIn)
   s = fgetl(myFileIn); % read line by line
   fprintf(myFileOut,'& & & %s\\\\\r\n',s); % write line by line and add \\ before newline
end

fclose(myFileIn)
fclose(myFileOut)
```

The result will be stored in `myResult2File.txt` and will look like this:

```
& & & 0.9801&0.9025&0.7225&0.6400&0.4900&0.4444&0.4225&0.3600&0.3025&0.2500\\
& & & 0.0198&0.0950&0.2550&0.3200&0.4200&0.4444&0.4550&0.4800&0.4950&0.5000\\
& & & 0.0001&0.0025&0.0225&0.0400&0.0900&0.1111&0.1225&0.1600&0.2025&0.2500\
```

By the way, `myResult1File.txt` looks like this:

```
0.9801&0.9025&0.7225&0.6400&0.4900&0.4444&0.4225&0.3600&0.3025&0.2500
0.0198&0.0950&0.2550&0.3200&0.4200&0.4444&0.4550&0.4800&0.4950&0.5000
0.0001&0.0025&0.0225&0.0400&0.0900&0.1111&0.1225&0.1600&0.2025&0.2500
```

The `LaTeX` file could look like this (I recommend using the `booktabs` package for example):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=170mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
  {\large\textbf{\hspace*{1.0cm}Table of the Binominal Distribution}}
\end{center}

Here you go\ldots

\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|*{11}r|} % *{11}r -> rrrrrrrrrrr
\hline
$n \downarrow$ & $k \downarrow$ & $p \to $ & 0.01 & 0.05 & 0.15 & 0.20 & 0.30 & 1/3 & 0.35 & 0.40 & 0.45 & 0.50\\
\hline
2 & 0 &  & 0.9801&0.9025&0.7225&0.6400&0.4900&0.4444&0.4225&0.3600&0.3025&0.2500\\
  & 1 &  & 0.0198&0.0950&0.2550&0.3200&0.4200&0.4444&0.4550&0.4800&0.4950&0.5000\\
  & 2 &  & 0.0001&0.0025&0.0225&0.0400&0.0900&0.1111&0.1225&0.1600&0.2025&0.2500\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The `PDF` file will then look like this:

[image]

To compare with the original:

[image]

Damn, I now see that I **forgot** `p=0.10` and `p=0.49` but you get the idea anyway.

**Remark:** There seems to be a little rounding error in your professors table (compare n=2,k=0,p=0.1). Or **Matlab** is wrong.

**Another Remark:** Why do you need still this kind of table nowadays?! Isn't it outdated like a `sin` or `log` table :)?

Comment: I would recommend using `*11r` instead of `rrrrrrrrrrr`, easier to read and change. Also you could modify the MATLAB code to output all columns of the table and then just use `\input` to include it. This way it will save the trouble of copy-n-paste.

Comment: @mythealias: I agree totally. I just had not enough time to do it better (I am supposed to work on my thesis right now ;)).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I'm pretty bad at using MatLab, but I will copy your solution when I come back home (I have MatLab installed in the PC). Anyway, I would prefer a LaTeX based solution, where the calculus was made by the same program which compiles my document. Good luck with your thesis.

Comment: @mythealias Actually `*{11}r` is needed.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I edited the code accordingly. Thx.