# Autosum Table contents in LaTeX

Tags: tables, calculations

I am trying to add the contents of a latex table, having something like this in mind:

[How can I automatically calculate sums in a LaTeX table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3851/how-can-i-automatically-calculate-sums-in-a-latex-table)

But this solution does not work for me... Is there any other way ?

Comment: Exactly what doesn't work for you and why?

Comment: Calctab and spreadtab are a bit complicated...there is not other alternative ?

Answer (score 2):

I once had the same wish: to do it all in one `.tex-file`: write my text, do my calculations, have my comments, in other words, to have one file for a task and not multiple files.

I had a look into `spreadtab` and found it much to complicated and by the way I was not sure that it would always give the right result.

OK, some years ago the `LuaTeX`-hype started, and I learned to program `tabulars` in `Lua` inside `LaTeX` files. `Lua` proved to be reliable, but again, at the price of being more than a bit complicated!

Then a software called [orgmode](http://orgmode.org/) drew my attention. Emacs -- which you need to run orgmode -- is a beast and orgmode itself needed some time to learn. But the documentation is very good and improved daily (sigh). Orgmodes includes a mode called "orgtbl" (orgmode table), which is simple and mighty enough. But beware: learning Emacs and orgmode is a project for quite a time. On the other hand, you get the means to do all you work for one matter in one file.

Besides that, if calculations become somewhat more difficult, I use `LibreOffice` and convert the table to `LaTeX` by using `calc2latex`.