# longtabu: put running total of some columns under the header on each page

Tags: longtable, calculations, tabu

so, I have a longtabu table spanning several pages. The table has a header, that needs to be repeated on each page. Some of the columns are numerical amounts, and I would like to put a row presenting a running total at the top of each page, just below the header.

So, I started off of what I found here: 
[How to print subtotals in each page of a long table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151380/how-to-print-subtotals-in-each-page-of-a-long-table/173202#173202)
and modified the code a little to be able to sum floating point numbers (the modification is in one of the answers to that question).

Now, I figured out how to move the running total to the header, instead of the footer, of the page. Still, as I said, I need also the original header to show up at each page, before the running total. However, when I typeset the MWE that you can find below here, I see two problems in the generated PDF:

- The running total row is badly aligned
- after the end of the table, I get an additional page with just the header and the (badly aligned) running total, which is undesireable.

I understand (I think!) the cause of the second problem, but cannot find a solution (it is probably beyond my understanding of longtabu's innards). As for the first problem, I can't figure it out.

So, without further ado, here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[textheight=9\baselineskip]{geometry}
\newcount\zzz
\def\foo{}
\def\zz#1{#1%
\global\advance\zzz#1\relax
\marks1 {\the\zzz}%
}
\marks1{0}

\newlength\yyy
\setlength{\yyy}{0pt}
\def\yy#1{#1
\global\addtolength{\yyy}{#1pt}\relax
\marks2 {\the\yyy}
}
\marks2{0}

\makeatletter
    \def\LT@output{
            \global\advance\c@LT@chunks\@M
            \LT@bchunk
            \edef\tmp{\topmarks1 } 
                \copy\LT@head\\
                running total: & \ifx\tmp\@empty\else \botmarks1 \fi& \ifx\tmp\@empty\else \strip@pt\dimexpr\botmarks2 \fi
            \LT@echunk
            \setbox\LT@head\box\z@
            \setbox\LT@foot\box\z@
            \LT@get@widths
            \global\advance\c@LT@chunks-\@M
                \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
                \@makecol
                \@outputpage
                \global\vsize\@colroom
            \copy\LT@head\nobreak
        }       
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{l|l|l}
Var&Val1&Val2 \endhead
xxxxxxxx&yyyyyyy&yyyyyy\\
xxxxzzzzzzzzzzzzzxx&yyyyyyy&yyyyyy\endfoot% not typeset but needs to be bigger than the foot that is used.
&&\endlastfoot
a & \zz{1} & \yy{0}\\
b & \zz{2} & \yy{0}\\
c & \zz{5} & \yy{0}\\
d & \zz{7} & \yy{0}\\
e & \zz{1} & \yy{0}\\
f & \zz{9} & \yy{0}\\
g & \zz{2} & \yy{0}\\
h & \zz{3} & \yy{0}\\
i & \zz{1} & \yy{1}\\
j & \zz{6} & \yy{6}\\
k & \zz{8} & \yy{8}\\
l & \zz{3} & \yy{3.2}\\
m & \zz{2} & \yy{2.67}\\
n & \zz{1} & \yy{1.1}\\
o & \zz{4} & \yy{4}\\
p & \zz{8} & \yy{8.05}\\
q & \zz{3} & \yy{3}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

And here's a screenshot of the result:

[image: result]

Thanks in advance for any help that might come. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, actually I found the answer. If you look at the question I started from (link provided above), you'll see that D. Carlisle had provided a more complete example. I had removed the whole first part of the if, which basically deals with the end of the table. Putting that back in (and adapting it) solved problem number 2. :)
As for problem number 1, I still don't understand, but I settled for explicitly repeating the header line in my added chunk of table, that will be good enough for now.
Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[textheight=9\baselineskip]{geometry}
\newcount\zzz
\def\foo{}
\def\zz#1{#1%
\global\advance\zzz#1\relax
\marks1 {\the\zzz}%
}
\marks1{0}

\newlength\yyy
\setlength{\yyy}{0pt}
\def\yy#1{#1
\global\addtolength{\yyy}{#1pt}\relax
\marks2 {\the\yyy}
}
\marks2{0}

\makeatletter
    \def\LT@output{
        \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi
            \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
                \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
            \else
                \LT@bchunk
                    Var&Val1&Val2 \\
                    running total: & \ifx\tmp\@empty\else \botmarks1 \fi& \ifx\tmp\@empty\else \strip@pt\dimexpr\botmarks2 \fi
                \LT@echunk
                \setbox\LT@foot\box\z@
                \LT@get@widths
                \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
                \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
                    \dimen@\pagegoal
                    \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
                    \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
                        \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\z@\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
                        \@makecol
                        \@outputpage
                        \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@head}%
                    \fi
                \fi
                \global\@colroom\@colht
                \global\vsize\@colht
                %\vbox
                {\unvbox\z@\nobreak\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi}%
            \fi
        \else
            \global\advance\c@LT@chunks\@M
            \LT@bchunk
                \edef\tmp{\topmarks1 } 
                Var&Val1&Val2 \\
                running total: & \ifx\tmp\@empty\else \botmarks1 \fi& \ifx\tmp\@empty\else \strip@pt\dimexpr\botmarks2 \fi
            \LT@echunk
            \setbox\LT@head\box\z@
            \setbox\LT@foot\box\z@
            \setbox\LT@lastfoot\box\z@
            \LT@get@widths
            \global\advance\c@LT@chunks\@M
            \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
            \@makecol
            \@outputpage
            \global\vsize\@colroom
            \copy\LT@head\nobreak   
        \fi 
        }       
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{l|l|l}
Var&Val1&Val2 \endhead
xxxxzzzzzzzzzzzzzxx&yyyyyyy&yyyyyy\endfoot% not typeset but needs to be bigger than the foot that is used.
 a & b & c \endlastfoot
a & \zz{1} & \yy{0}\\
b & \zz{2} & \yy{0}\\
c & \zz{5} & \yy{0}\\
d & \zz{7} & \yy{0}\\
e & \zz{1} & \yy{0}\\
f & \zz{9} & \yy{0}\\
g & \zz{2} & \yy{0}\\
h & \zz{3} & \yy{0}\\
i & \zz{1} & \yy{1}\\
j & \zz{6} & \yy{6}\\
k & \zz{8} & \yy{8}\\
l & \zz{3} & \yy{3.2}\\
m & \zz{2} & \yy{2.67}\\
n & \zz{1} & \yy{1.1}\\
o & \zz{4} & \yy{4}\\
p & \zz{8} & \yy{8.05}\\
q & \zz{3} & \yy{3}\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```