# How to print a page number to a repeating header of a longtable?

Tags: tables, header-footer, longtable, page-numbering, lastpage

The table header gets generated once and only prints:

> Page 1 of 2

... on each and every page. Is there any way update the page number in the `longtable` header to reflect the *actual* current page, i.e., in this case:

> Page 2 of 2

Speaking of this *minimal* example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| c | c |} \hline
  \textbf{Foo, bar.} & \textbf{Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}} \\
  \hline \endhead
  \hline \endfoot
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: not easily (you may prefer supertabular) longtable headings are only typeset once into a box. However there is an answer here with a patch if you are feeling brave, I'll see if I can find it again....

Comment: this shows a way to alter the longtable foot https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151380/how-to-print-subtotals-in-each-page-of-a-long-table/157193#157193

Comment: Does David's link give you a suitable approach?  If so, let us know, so that we can close the question as a duplicate of that...

Comment: No, it's about calculating subtotals in a longtabletable footer. It faces similar issues but I only get a gist of the complexity involved. This hardly answers my question, but thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend you using the `supertabular` environment. This will allow you to customize headers and footers (called `tails`) which way you want.

Here is a simple example based on your post:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}
 \tablehead{\hline\textbf{Foo, bar.} & \textbf{Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}\\\hline }
  \tablefirsthead{\hline\textbf{Foo, bar.} & \textbf{Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}\\\hline}
  \tabletail{\hline}
  \tablelasttail{\hline}
\begin{supertabular}{| c | c |} 
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

A couple of examples:

[image]

[image]

I provide a new version with `booktabs` just to typeset the table better (in my opinion), since I removed the vertical and horizontal separators and used the `booktabs` rules:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs,supertabular}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}
 \tablehead{\toprule\textbf{Foo, bar.} & \textbf{Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}\\\midrule }
  \tablefirsthead{\hline\textbf{Foo, bar.} & \textbf{Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}\\\midrule}
  \tabletail{\bottomrule}
  \tablelasttail{\bottomrule}
\begin{supertabular}{c  c} 
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
  Lorem Ipsum & John Doe \\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

And its examples

[image]

[image]

*Note* please note that in `supertabular` jargon:

- the `tablefirsthead` of course is the header of the first page for the table,
- `tablehead` is the head for the subsequent pages,
- `tabletail` is the footer for all the pages, save the last one,
- `tablelasttail` is the last footer